# @ngrx/data How to cancel request providing with getAll, getWithQuery, getByKey

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-entity, switchmap, angular-ngrx-data

I use ngrx/data in my app.

I have a very quick application.
You can select something on UI and I need to update my view.  A user can do it very quickly, I do not need any previous data from previous requests in that case.

But when I add switchMap - my request doesn't cancel.

```js
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'nrwl-test-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  test$ = new Subject();
  userEntity: EntityCollectionService<User>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, entityDefinition: EntityDefinitionService, entityServices: EntityServices) {
    entityDefinition.registerMetadataMap({
      User: {},
    });

    this.userEntity = entityServices.getEntityCollectionService<User>('User');
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.test$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => { 
        // return this.http.get('api/user') // switchMap works here
        return this.userEntity.getAll() // switchMap doesn't work here
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  onClick() {
    this.test$.next(Math.random());
  }
}
```

I have "@ngrx/data": ^0.10.2

but I check it on the latest version 11.0.1 - and I have the same behavior.

I found a workaround just use httpClient for it and after the success request I update my entityCache. But I do not like this approach.

As I understand entity service return always AnonymousSubject instead of Observable.
And it is a reason why I can not cancel my request. But maybe I can do it in the right way?

Answer (score 2):

ngrx-data base service offers a `cancel` method that can be used
to request to cancel a query or save operation

[image]

You just need to call that method on an entity service that extends `EntityCollectionServiceBase`

Create a method in the service that generates the correlationId

```js
public generateCorrelationId(): EntityActionOptions {
    this.currentCorrelationId = this.correlationIdGenerator.next();

    const entityActionOptions: EntityActionOptions = {
      correlationId: this.currentCorrelationId
    }

    return entityActionOptions;
  }
```

Lets say you want to make be able to cancel you getWithQuery

```js
let entityActionOptions = this.generateCorrelationId()
this.getWithQuery(queryParams, entityActionOptions);
```

then to cancel you just call the method passing the correlationId

```js
this.mileageTrackingManagmentService.cancel(entityActionOptions.correlationId)
```